# Can't run my web application on jetty

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jetty

I am using **Spring MVC** + **Spring Security** + **Hibernate** and **Jetty** as Container to build my web application. But something goes wrong when I run Jetty.
Here is the output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java" -DSTOP.PORT=0 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -DOPTIONS=jmx -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -classpath "D:\jetty-distribution-9.3.7.v20160115\start.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\lib\tools.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main --module=jmx C:\Windows\Temp\context2config\jetty-contexts.xml
[2016-03-05 03:34:45,214] Artifact DVDExchange:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server http port: 8080
WARNING: System properties and/or JVM args set.  Consider using --dry-run or --exec
2016-03-05 15:34:45.818:INFO::main: Logging initialized @525ms
2016-03-05 15:34:45.864:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not recommended.  See documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
STOP.PORT=4813
STOP.KEY=1nury94gxsbuo
2016-03-05 15:34:46.006:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.7.v20160115
2016-03-05 15:34:46.025:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///D:/jetty-distribution-9.3.7.v20160115/webapps/] at interval 1
2016-03-05 15:34:46.029:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///C:/Windows/Temp/context2deploy/] at interval 1
2016-03-05 15:34:46.061:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@7a0ac6e3{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2016-03-05 15:34:46.061:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @767ms
Connected to server
[2016-03-05 03:34:46,298] Artifact DVDExchange:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
2016-03-05 15:34:48.939:INFO:/:Scanner-1: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2016-03-05 15:34:49.269:INFO:/:Scanner-1: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
мар 05, 2016 3:34:49 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
мар 05, 2016 3:34:49 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Mar 05 15:34:49 YEKT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
мар 05, 2016 3:34:49 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
мар 05, 2016 3:34:49 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 247 ms
2016-03-05 15:34:49.575:INFO:/:Scanner-1: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
мар 05, 2016 3:34:49 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
мар 05, 2016 3:34:49 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sat Mar 05 15:34:49 YEKT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
мар 05, 2016 3:34:49 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
мар 05, 2016 3:34:49 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.dvdexchange.SpringMVC.controller.MainController.home(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
мар 05, 2016 3:34:49 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sat Mar 05 15:34:49 YEKT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
мар 05, 2016 3:34:50 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sat Mar 05 15:34:49 YEKT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
мар 05, 2016 3:34:50 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
2016-03-05 15:34:50.053:WARN:oejd.DeploymentManager:Scanner-1: Unable to reach node goal: started
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:428)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
[2016-03-05 03:34:50,065] Artifact DVDExchange:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

I don't know the reason why it does not work, but maybe you could help me with it? Look at output above and analyze it. As long as I am not enough excperienced in debugging I can't do it by myself in proper way. I think this parts are the most important

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
......
......
```

it tells us about something about hibernate is not found. But I don't know what exactly. All Frameworks dependencies including Hibernate are in the pom.xml file (using Maven).

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I used Jetty as IntelliJ IDEA plugin and configured it this way
[Server configuraton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDCE0.png)
[Deployment configuraton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tsn2R.png)

And there is also WARNING in the output about my context root (see Deployment conf above).

```
2016-03-05 15:34:45.864:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not recommended.  See documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
```

I hope you guys can help me with it.
Thanks in dvance!

Comment: You need to check is there any `hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar` in the classpath of jetty. `HibernateException` resides in that jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that the .class file is not found by your web-app inside the war file. You can see if hibernate.jar file is present inside your webapp folder `WEB-INF\lib`.

**Solution** (IntelliJ):

1. Open your Project structure.
2. Select Artifacts from the left side options.
3. From your war file in the "OutputLayout" tab browse to `WEB-INF/lib`.
4. Add the library containing `hibernate.jar` into the folder.
5. Redeploy your project.

Also try this, Go to `File -> Project Structure -> Libraries` and add the directory folder that has the JARs. This will add the jar to your classpath.

Comment: You helped me so I highly appreciate that. I marked your advice as accepted. Thank so much man! Long live! :-)